# Why is "If... then" structure not working for a list?

Tags: plotting, conditional

This code below gives me 4 spherical surfaces center at the origin with radius 1,2,3, and 4.

```
SphericalPlot3D[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi},
 Mesh -> None,
 Boxed -> False,
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.3]}]
```

I'm not sure why adding the "If...then" function does not yield the same result given that it has been assigned a value of True.

```
SphericalPlot3D[
 If[True, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {5}], {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi},
 Mesh -> None,
 Boxed -> False,
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.3]}]
```

Why is it not working?  Can you please explain?  How can I make this work retaining the If function?

Comment: Since `SphericalPlot3D` has the attribute `HoldAll` you need to wrap the `If` statement in `Evaluate`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Bob Hanlon above...

"Since SphericalPlot3D has the attribute HoldAll you need to wrap the If statement in Evaluate."

Works perfect.

BTW... Is this how I credit an answer to someone that left their answer in a comment?  I would like to give them credit.

Comment: Mathematicians here on SE are a lazy bunch :-), and will often offer a quick answer in a comment, rather than having to write a full answer. They know comments won't get them rep, but they don't care. I think crediting the answer's originator like you did is perfect.